# Positive eigenvalues and Schur complements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, schur-complement

For a symmetric matrix,

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
  A & C\\
  C^{\top} & D
\end{array}\right)$$

it is well known that $M$ is positive definite if and only if $A$ and the Shur complement $M\backslash A = D-CA^{-1}C^T$ are positive definite.

Is there a generalization of this fact, for non-symmetric matrices? Can we claim that:

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
  A & C\\
  B & D
\end{array}\right)$$

has all eigenvalues with positive real part, if and only if $A$ and $M\backslash A = D - CA^{-1}B$ have eigenvalues with positive real parts too?

I am particularly interested in matrices $M$ which are not symmetric, but for which $B=-C^T$.

Comment: if  $B=-C^T$ then $\mathbf x^T M \mathbf x =  \mathbf x^T \left(\begin{array}{cc}
  A & \mathbf 0 \\
  \mathbf 0 & D
\end{array}\right)\mathbf x$  for any $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$... i.e. you have  block diagonal matrix and add a skew symmetric matrix to it which is irrelevant for the quadratic form, so this is PD iff $A\succ \mathbf 0$  and $D\succ \mathbf 0$

Comment: @user8675309 Yes, I have edited the question. I am actually referring to the real parts of the eigenvalues of the matrices. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: so you changed the question and its title from being about positive definite to positive real components of eigenvalues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a counterexample where $A$ and $M\backslash A$ have both positive eigenvalues, but $M$ has an eigenvalue with negative real part, namely
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & -2 \\
2 & -2
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
A has eigenvalue $1$ and $M\backslash A$ has eigenvalue 2, but $M$ has two eigenvalues with real part $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ok thanks! This completely destroys my original proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Try
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1\\
-1 &2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The only eigenvalue is $1$, but $A=0$.